# How to check for parameter presence: params.require(:data) or params[:data].present? and why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

What is the best way of checking for parameter presence inside of a controller action:

```
params.require(:data) # will raise an ActionController::ParameterMissing error if the parameter is not found in the request

params[:data].present? # check if something is in the parameter
```

Which should be the preferred way, and why?

The first way will throw an error, which will need to be handled. The second way can be used in a conditional. Both ways could be used to enable the controller action to return an error message that the parameter is missing.

Comment: It seems my answer may have been misunderstood in what it was trying to get across, so i have updated it to explain in a bit more detail, hope you have the time to take a read :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you may have a slight misunderstanding in the purpose of `params.require`.

If your aim is to simply check for the existance of a certain parameter to organise the flow of code, then yes always use `.present?`

The core aim of `.require` and Strong Params is not to check for existance of a parameter or not, but to allow for the creation of a whitelist for your parameters, and raise an exception when any parameter not specifically whitelisted attempts to pass, or an essential parameter is missing. a very different purpose altogether. I suggest a look at [StrongParameters api](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

The general aim for StrongParams and .require / .permit is to protect your database, they are used to protect your data when mass-assigning to a model. As I am sure you are aware with an in production project, your (or your customers) data is everything, and NOT using a whitelist for parameters is an extremely irresponsible thing to be doing.

**EDIT**

It seems my point may have been taken the wrong way due to the bulk of it talking about StrongParams, so let me explain a little more.

What i was hoping you would understand through the explanation of the purpose of strong params, is that it is not a viable choice for use in a mere presence check. The other answers have also stated that they recommend the use of `.present?`, however the reasoning is not a solid foundation for *why* this is better.

Code readability is of course important, but code readability has nothing to do with handling errors, you can very easily write code that is readable and handles exceptions. therefore code readability shouldn't even come into the equation, because that is just based on how well you can write your exception handling logic.

And as for not wanting errors on a production app, that is a completely counter intuitive point, because the whole purpose of throwing and handling exceptions is exactly for that reason, to stop errors occurring on a production app, avoiding silent logic that may have small unexpected bugs and could cause problems down the line.

The core principle as to *why* `.present?` is the obvious choice is in the question itself:

> How to check for parameter presence

All code is written for a purpose, to solve a given problem, or to provide functionality suitable for a given need. So what should be considered is what is the *purpose* of `.present?` and what is the purpose `.require`. The purpose of `.present?` is fairly simple, checking for presence and returning a Boolean result in *either* case (meaning you can put it together with other tests using `||`, not possible with `.require`), it fulfills the needs of the question.

Now lets take a look at `.require`, which is a feature from `ActionController::StrongParameters` module. A quick look of the API states the purpose of the StrongParameters module:

> It provides an interface for protecting attributes from end-user assignment.

Is this the purpose that you are seeking, now of course the question you asked is quite a broad one, and its difficult to read the intent from it, but from the bare question "I want to check parameter presence", we can conclude that `.require` or any StrongParameters features is not *purposed* for this.

Whew! that was long, sorry for the mini Essay there, but I want to bring focus to the fact that, while the other answers bring some topics are valid and should be considered, (not just in this question but in all code). I hope to bring to your attention that there is WAY more to consider than simple code readability or not wanting to handle errors, which can both be solved very easily in a variety of solutions. Even small simple decisions like this should be considered with a perspective that has much more core principles of programming in mind as well.

**Long story short**: I *can* hammer a nail in with the handle of a screwdriver, but that is not its purpose, and if I keep doing it i'm eventually gona have a bad time.

Comment: Since you've asked me for my opinion, I'll give it to ya :p. I think we can both agree that `present?` is better in this case.  But I would disagree with your assertion that you need to follow the Rails API word-for-word on what to do in regards to `.require` and `present?`. In my opinion, I think that methods like `.require`, and `.present?` are just means to an end. If `.require` returned the object or false (vs. right now, returning object or error), it really IMO, would not make a difference which one you would use, as both would give you the same result.

Comment: I mean it is personal preference, but in my opinion, I wouldn’t take the Rails description too literally, unless there was some programming/functional reason not to use a particular method outside of the use case described in the API. In this case, I don’t think that there is one.

Comment: @the12 thank you for the response and opinion :D. My Assertion isnt that you need to follow the Rails API, my point has nothing to do with rails, but with core programming principles, my assertion is that you shouldnt use code not designed for a purpose, and shouldn't repeat code, when there is already code designed for that purpose, and rewriting `.require` to fit your need, when `.present?` already does it is exactly that, plus you cant use .require with an else statement, because it will raise an error, the same reason you cant use it with a `||` operator.

Comment: and the reason you can't use it with else or || is beacuse, by design, it was not made for the simple purpose of "is this param present?" but for the purpose of "This Params __must__ be input for mass assignment", of course you can write an inline rescue to fit it to use an else like `if (params.require(:test) rescue false); do something; else; do something else;` but then we have code repetition, and we are just reinventing the wheel. Not to mention just plain ugly code.

Comment: I think we can both agree that we both agree on things... :)

Comment: things are great things to be agreeing on :P

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, and discussion. I am aware of the purpose of `.require`, and agree in general with the principle of using something for what it was meant for, although you could argue, for a particular case, that "if it quacks like a duck, then it's a duck". I wasn't using `.require` in a conditional, just stating it on a separate line in the code (with a comment that it could throw an error), and handling the error down below. See my comment on @the12 answer for more info on my use case as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you answered your own question. If you prefer to handle exceptions, use `require`. If you like to use conditions instead, use `present?`.

For me the second way is preferred cause it reduces the chance that my app will crash on production (if I failed to handle exceptions properly).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to raise an error in regards to if a parameter is present or not.

I would personally say to go for `.present` in the sense that you could always use it in a conditional, and allows for better code readability, vs. alternative of the messy, and complicated nature of handling errors.

Even under the hypothetical assumption that the parameter was not present, you could still render another page should you choose. IMO, in the specific case where you have a simply looking for the presence of an error, really don't see a reason why you'd want the application to throw an error vs. false. Even the worse-case hypothetical situation of a parameter not being present when using `.present?` can be appropriately handled by a simple if and else statement:

```
if (some value).present?
  render("some_page")
else 
  render("error_page")
end
```

Comment: The reason you would want the application to throw an error is because the purpose of `params.require` and `params.permit` is not for general presence checking. The sole purpose of using StrongParams is to create a safe whitelisted set of arguments for mass assignment to a model, to protect your database and your customers business.

Comment: If you look at the question more closely, the author asks what is the best way to check parameters. Not what is the best way to mass-load parameters inside an object, in which case yes, strong parameters (`.require`) is the best and recommended way to do this in Rails 4+.  Although I can't say definitively what his use case is, if it is indeed a simple presence check (just want to check whether parameters are present), then I still do believe that `.present` would offer everything that `.require` would offer + better code readability.

Comment: yes `.present` is the obvious choice, but the point I am trying to make is, that `.require` shouldn't even be considered for use in simple presence check because that is not its prupose, therefore the problem isn't really one of code readability, more of code purpose.

Comment: added more to my answer to try and explain what I mean a bit more, we are both on the same page answer wise, but I just want to bring attention to the fact that the reasoning should be considered with more in mind, would appreciate it if you took a read :)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting discussion. I wasn't naturally thinking of using `.require`, but I had some problems getting `.present?` to work properly with checking for a file `:blob_data` upload, and then `.require` became a workaround that seemed to work. However, I can't reproduce the problem now, so I can't say for sure if it's really a difference between `.present?` and `.require` with regards to checking blob data (presumably an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`).